# Compatibility matrix for XML::LibXSLT with libxslt and libxml2

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, xml-libxml, libxslt

How can I tell if XML::LibXSLT-1.94 is most compatible with libxslt 1.1.29 or  libxslt 1.1.28 ?

I have [this report](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/1c6e7ce2-0a1b-11e5-a857-d91bc75d5552) which says

`Compiled against:    libxslt 10128, libxml2 20902
 Running:             libxslt 10128, libxml2 20902`

Does this mean its **only** compatible with libxslt 1.1.28 and libxml2 2.9.2 on that particular version of OS ?

If not, is there any compatibility matrix that I can refer to ?

Comment: It means: the particular report is generated using the libxslt version 10128. For me the `make test` prints: `Compiled against:    libxslt 10129, libxml2 20904`

Comment: The easiest way would be to try. And then send a report to cpantesters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compile XML::LibXSLT with libxslt 1.1.18 or newer. Only versions 1.1.25 and 1.1.27 are [blacklisted](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.95/Makefile.PL#L59). Switching to a *newer* libxslt version *without recompiling* XML::LibXSLT is also supported. Switching to an *older* version of libxslt can result in a runtime link failure or a warning message. But AFAIK, 1.1.28 and 1.1.29 can be used interchangeably.